# Realm Primary Key Constraint Exception: Value already exists

Tags: android, realm

When I loop through my list to add all objects to `Realm` they are being overwritten by each of the following so that `RecyclerView` shows only one image.

For now I've got 3 cases:

- Calling `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` everytime overwrites saved object.
- If I try to call `insert()` with `@PrimaryKey` set the `RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: null` is thrown.
- When I remove `@PrimaryKey` annotation `Realm` completes copping and `RecyclerView` successfully show pictures but in further all objects might have own duplicate and that's not a way out.

Here are my classes:

*RealmObject class*

```
  public class Picture extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey String picURL;
    //getters/setters
}
```

*Handler where I directly iterate through list in my `ImageModel.class`*

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
        super.dispatchMessage(msg);
        final List<Picture> list = (List<Picture>) msg.obj;

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                for (Picture current : list) {
                    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(current);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

How to save each and every object to Realm without being duplicated?

Comment: Handler? What? Why?

Comment: `RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: null` then your `imgURL` field is `null` when you call `copyToRealmOrUpdate()`

Comment: Did the answer help you ?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks. The problem was in thread collision. I'll post the solution in detail later.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the `@primaryKey` . And here's how you'd update, from your code:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            for (Picture current : list) {
                Picture db = realm.where(Picture.class).equalTo("picURL",picURL).findFirst();
                db.setOtherMethod(true);
                db.setAnotherMethod("hello");
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see, the key is to search for the primary key object, and then edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are inserting the data with the same Primary key, use `insertOrUpdate` function to do so.